# Linux - Read a record till to the end with awk

Tags: linux, awk

lets say i have this text from the logfile:

```
Jun 10 11:09:07 mylinux daemon.notice openvpn[3710]: TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: 1.22.333.444:1111
```

But i don't need the part between "mylinux" and the next colon:
Thats the part i try to remove: `daemon.notice openvpn[3710]`

I "solved" it with awk, but thats not a good solution.

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20;}' /var/log/messages
```

I just wrote many "$" to cover as many lines as possible, but this won't work if there are more lines then $ ofc.

I know i can check how many lines exist with "NF", but i don't know how to use this information.

Thats how records in a logfile look like:

```
Jun 10 11:47:29 FeketeLUA daemon.notice openvpn[3710]: LZO compression initialized
Jun 10 11:47:29 FeketeLUA daemon.notice openvpn[3710]: Attempting to establish TCP connection with 5.55.222.34:1122 [nonblock]
Jun 10 11:47:30 FeketeLUA daemon.notice openvpn[3710]: TCP connection established with 12.11.123.444:1111
```

Comment: so the desired output is the same line without the part starting in mylinux and finishing in TCPv4_CLIENT?

Comment: In this case the desired output would be:

Jun 10 11:09:07 mylinux TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: 1.22.333.444:1111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think regexes are the way to go here. This is possible with awk but easier with Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/mylinux\K.*?(?=TCPv4_CLIENT)/ /' /var/log/messages
```

Where

- Everything before `\K` has to be there but is not considered part of the match (that is later replaced)
- `.*?` matches any string non-greedily (i.e., the shortest possible match is taken rather than the longest)
- `(?=TCPv4_CLIENT)` is a lookahead term that matches an empty string if (and only if) it is followed by `TCPv4_CLIENT`)

So the regex will match the part between `mylinux` and the first `TCPv4_CLIENT` that comes after it and replace it with a space.

**Update:** It's actually easier for the changed question since the ending delimiter is part of the removed match and we don't need the lookahead term for it:

```
perl -pe 's/FeketeLUA\K.*?://' /var/log/messages
```

`\K` and `.*?` continue to work as described before.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! But the problem is, that the text "TCPv4_CLIENT" is variable because it is a logfile. So i think i can only solve this with awk

Comment: So you want everything after `FeketeLUA` to the next `colon` removed, is that correct? Try `perl -pe 's/FeketeLUA\K.*?://'`

Comment: Yes. I only want to delete
"daemon.notice openvpn[3710]" and keep the rest, thank you! Do you know a solution with awk too, because i don't have the ability to install perl on my device.

Comment: Not having Perl is rather unusual. I'd suggest `sed 's/\(FeketeLUA\)[^:]*:/\1/'` in that case. With awk, you could write `awk '{ sub(/FeketeLUA[^:]*:/, "FeketeLUA") } 1'`. The duplication is necessary because awk doesn't have back references (unless you can rely on GNU awk extensions, which I don't expect you to be able to if you don't have Perl).

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort, it worked perfectly!

Comment: Nothing unusual about not having perl. Many of the UNIX boxes I use at work don't have perl and it won't be installed on them. It's one the [lesser] reasons I've never bothered to learn it.

Answer (score 2):

I must be missing something because it sounds like all you need is:

```
$ sed -r 's/(mylinux)[^:]+:/\1/' file
Jun 10 11:09:07 mylinux TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: 1.22.333.444:1111

$ awk '{x="mylinux"; sub(x"[^:]+:",x)} 1' file
Jun 10 11:09:07 mylinux TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: 1.22.333.444:1111
```

If instead you wanted to remove between 2 points without mentioning "mylinux" for example then that'd just be:

```
$ sed -r 's/(([^ ]+ +){4})[^:]+: /\1/' file
Jun 10 11:09:07 mylinux TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: 1.22.333.444:1111

$ awk '{print gensub(/(([^ ]+ +){4})[^:]+: /,"\\1","")}' file
Jun 10 11:09:07 mylinux TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: 1.22.333.444:1111
```

That 2nd awk command used gawk for gensub() - with other awks you'd use match()+substr().

Comment: The way it was described in the question before made it look as though they wanted to remove between two points, but yeah i think this is what they actually want.

Comment: @User112638726 I now added a version that just removes between 2 points in case that is what was desired. Thanks for the background!

Comment: yes i wanted to remove content between 2 points, next time i will try to make my question as obvious as possible. Thank you sirs

Answer (score 1):

Gnu awk way

```
awk 'match($0,/(.*mylinux).*(TCPv4_CLIENT.*)/,a){print a[1],a[2]}' file

Jun 10 11:09:07 mylinux TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: 1.22.333.444:1111
```

Capture the bits you want in array a, then prints them.

Comment: Thank you, but the part "TCPv4_CLIENT" is variable because it is part of the logged record. Sorry, maybe i did not expressed myselve good enough.

Comment: @EdwardBlack What do mean is a variable ? Please show how it is set in your question or provide another case where it is different.

Comment: Ok, my fault. I thought you guys know how a logfile looks like. Here are 3 more examples

Comment: @EdwardBlack Add them to your question, don't post information in comments.